# GIN index not working with `SELECT 1` but it works if I do `SELECT COUNT(*)` on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have the following query

```sql
> explain analyze SELECT 1 AS one FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."email" 
ILIKE '%email@gmail.com%' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.00..470.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2303.032..2303.033 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: 1
  ->  Seq Scan on public.orders  (cost=0.00..108200.10 rows=230 width=4) (actual time=2303.031..2303.031 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: 1
        Filter: ((orders.email)::text ~~* '%email@gmail.com%'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2309367
Planning Time: 0.195 ms
Execution Time: 2303.047 ms
```

If I run the same query but instead of using `SELECT 1` I use `SELECT COUNT(*)` the gin index (gin_trgm_ops) start to work

```sql
> explain analyze SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."email" 
ILIKE '%email@gmail.com%' LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

QUERY PLAN

Limit  (cost=1263.98..1263.99 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=18.074..18.075 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Aggregate  (cost=1263.98..1263.99 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=18.073..18.073 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orders  (cost=377.78..1263.40 rows=230 width=0) (actual time=18.062..18.067 rows=3 loops=1)
              Recheck Cond: ((email)::text ~~* '%email@gmail.com%'::text)
              Heap Blocks: exact=2
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_orders_on_email_gin  (cost=0.00..377.72 rows=230 width=0) (actual time=18.043..18.044 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((email)::text ~~* '%email@gmail.com%'::text)
Planning Time: 0.575 ms
Execution Time: 18.120 ms
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SELECT 1 ... LIMIT 1, it can stop early once it finds one qualifying row.  Since PostgreSQL misestimates how many qualifying rows there are, it misestimates how useful this stopping early will be.

The LIMIT doesn't do anything when used with COUNT(*) but without a GROUP BY, since only one row is returned anyway.  There is no stopping-early that can be done, as every qualifying row needs to be found in order to count them.

The crux of the matter is not SELECT 1 versus SELECT COUNT(*), it is a LIMIT that does something versus one that does not.